# Find objects only available in array1 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Here I have two array. I want to take value only available in Array1.
some scenario

1. if both have common item then return empty.
2. if both have not any common item then return all item of array1.
3. if array1 have item1 which are not aviable in array 2 then return item1 only

```js
var Array1 = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'item1'
}, {
    id : 2,
    name : 'item2'
}];
 var Array2 = [{
        id : 1,
        name : 'item1',
        expiredate : 2022
    },
    {   id : 3,
        name : 'item3',
        expiredate : 2022
    }
];

// now want a result array3 which contains the item only available in array1. for above examplle item2
```

Comment: Could you show expected result, as I'm not sure what the logic is here.

Comment: Your snippet is not a valid JavaScript.

Comment: result will be like   array3 = [{
    id = 2,
    name = 'item2'
}]                                                                                                    contains items only available in array1 not in array2

Comment: @SamarthPatel can you mark my answer as accepted if it worked please.

Answer (score 1):

I made a function that is basically Array difference but with a slight modification

```js
let Array1 = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'item1'
   }, 
   {
    id : 2,
    name : 'item2'
   }]
let Array2 = [{
        id : 1,
        name : 'item1',
        expiredate: 2022
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        name : 'item3',
        expiredate: 2022,
    }
]

function arr_diff(a1, a2){
  var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i].id] = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i].id]) {
            delete a[a2[i].id];
        }
    }

    for (var k in a) {
        a1.forEach(item => {
        
          if(item.id == k) diff.push(item);
        })
    }

    return diff;
}

let D = arr_diff(Array1, Array2)

console.log(D);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just the difference of `array1` from `array2` -

```js
var array1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'item1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'item2'
}];
var array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'item1',
    expiredate: 2022
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'item3',
    expiredate: 2022
  }
];

var array3 = array1.filter(b =>
  !array2.some(s => s.id === b.id && s.name === b.name));

console.log(array3);
```